# Cannot center view in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to center a view within a parent `RelativeLayout`:

```
private void addLoadingAnimation() {
    RelativeLayout mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.medical_supply_tile_activity);
    mainView.removeAllViews();
    GifView gifView = new GifView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    gifView.setId(R.id.loading_gif);
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    mainView.addView(gifView,layoutParams);
}
```

I have also tried adding `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);` before the `CENTER_IN_PARENT` line. Nothing seems to be working. It is always aligned to the bottom right.

Here is my parent view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context=".MedecineTileActivity"
    android:id="@id/medical_supply_tile_activity"
    android:layout_gravity="left">    
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `gravity=left` is because when the loading animation is removed, I insert fragments and want them to go to the left.

Comment: add `android:gravity="center"` in you `RelativeLayout `

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with TextViews and ImageViews by aligning the child View's right to the parent's right and also aligning the child View's left to the parent's left.

```
<TextView
            style="@style/NewTextM2"
            android:id="@+id/soft_dialog_info_item_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/<Parent>"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/<Parent>"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/<Parent>"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="item_text"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:maxLines="1" />
```

This will align the view to the bottom center of the parent.